# Sorting a string type MultiIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe with MultiIndex.

I need to sort first by 'Ccy' and then by 'Spot'. The issue is that 'Spot' index are strings, so it doesn't get sorted properly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['USDCLP', 'USDMXN', 'USDBRL','EURUSD'],
                                  ['500.50', '33.5', '109.40','88','101.89','1103.18']],
                                 names=['Ccy', 'Spot'])
col = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, idx, col)
df = df.sort_index(level=['Ccy','Spot'], ascending=True)

print df

                 A   B   C
Ccy    Spot               
EURUSD 101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
       33.5    NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       88      NaN NaN NaN
USDBRL 101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
       33.5    NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       88      NaN NaN NaN
USDCLP 101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
       33.5    NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       88      NaN NaN NaN
USDMXN 101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
       33.5    NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       88      NaN NaN NaN
```

I tried converting the index to floats first for then to be sorted like this:

```
df = df.index.levels[1].astype('float')
df = df.sort_index(level=['Ccy','Spot'], ascending=True)
```

But give the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'sort_index'
```

How can I sort the 'Spot' index in an ascending way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do  two steps

```
df=df.reset_index(level=1)

df.assign(Spot=df.Spot.astype(float)).set_index('Spot',append=True).sort_index()
Out[12]: 
                 A   B   C
Ccy    Spot               
EURUSD 33.50   NaN NaN NaN
       88.00   NaN NaN NaN
       101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
USDBRL 33.50   NaN NaN NaN
       88.00   NaN NaN NaN
       101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
USDCLP 33.50   NaN NaN NaN
       88.00   NaN NaN NaN
       101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
USDMXN 33.50   NaN NaN NaN
       88.00   NaN NaN NaN
       101.89  NaN NaN NaN
       109.40  NaN NaN NaN
       500.50  NaN NaN NaN
       1103.18 NaN NaN NaN
```